# operator addition class deals with arrays addition C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I'm a rookie of c#. I ran a simple test to get the sum of two arrays. Here is my example

```
       A                                B               Total
   date   Price                     date  Price       date  Price
   01/07  100                       01/07  50         01/07  150
   02/07  150                       02/07  30         02/07  180
```

I created two arrays:

```
string [,] A=new string[2,2]{{"01/07",100},{"02/07",150}};
string [,] B=new string[2,2]{{"01/07",50},{"02/07",30}};
string [,] c=new string [2,2];     
 for(int i=0;i<=A.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
  { 
    c[i,0]=A[i,0];
    c[i,1]=Convert.ToString(Convert.Todouble(A[i,1])-Convert.Todouble(B[i,1]));
  }
```

Here is my question:

Is that possible to create a class or function called Addition who does the same computation and at each time I only need to declare these two parameters?
 And how to do so?

For example: `class Addition(parameter1, parameter2)`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Technical answer to your question: Yes.

Comment: You can't have parameters in a class, but you can create a static method in that class with parameters. The body of your method would look just like what you wrote there, except with the parameter names where `A` and `B` are, and it would need to return an array `C`.

Comment: You can overload operators in C# yes. First, I think you should look into how to create types. It looks like you have an array with different types of data (date, value), so you should probably create a class or struct holding this data.

Comment: @ Ron Beyer could you tell me how to create this class by code? bcs I dont know how to write this class.thx

Comment: @dukroll - "How to create classes" seems sort of outside the bounds of what sorts of help are generally offered here. You could read something like [Microsoft's C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) to get started, and come back if you start implementing and run into issues.